# jq/js syntax :: var for textarea

Tags: jquery, syntax, var

I have a working ajax form that have now expanded to include a `textarea`.

Since I found this original var syntax for my input and select variables, I just want to confirm that `'brief_desc'     : $('textarea[name=briefDesc]').val(),` is correct?

See how it was added to the the expanded var below (2nd from bottom):

```
var formData = {
      // General Data
      'unit_id'     : $('input[name=unit_id]').val(),
      'title'       : $('input[name=title]').val(),
      'status'      : $('select[name=status]').val(),
      'tags'        : $('input[name=tags]').val(),
      'category'    : $('select[name=category]').val(),
      'access'      : $('select[name=access]').val(),
      // Promo Content
      'ad_id'       : $('input[name=adId]').val(),    
      'ad_title'    : $('input[name=adTitle]').val(),
      'image'       : $('input[name=adImage]').val(),
      'img_caption' : $('input[name=adCaption]').val(),
      'brief_desc'  : $('textarea[name=briefDesc]').val(),
      'btn_text'    : $('input[name=adButton]').val()
  };
```

Comment: When you ask "is it correct?", I think you have to explain what you want it to do and what does your testing show that it actually does?

Comment: also where is the relevant html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$('textarea[name=briefDesc]').val()` is the right syntax to retrieve the text input in your `<textarea>` element.

I was able to retrieve the text values of `textarea`'s in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `text()` method

```
$('textarea[name=briefDesc]').text()
```

```js
alert($('textarea[name=briefDesc]').text());
```

```html
<textarea name="briefDesc" cols="30" rows="10">this is the value</textarea>
```